# How to Fix a Broken BGE Animation

Tags: animation, game-engine, armature

I made an animation in the Blender Internal renderer with a robotic arm and a bone rig. the animation looks like this: [image] However, when I try to play that animation in the BGE, the red cube (palm) is thrown off to the side, out of the arm. Does anyone happen to know why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: We need more information: How does it look like (a screenshot should be sufficient), What objects/bones are involved? What relationship does they have? How do you play the animation?

Comment: Nevermind. I started the animation over from Scratch (remodeled the hand and everything) and it works fine in both now. Must've been something wrong with that specific cube.